# How to check if there a cell in the csv file is empty?

Tags: c#, csv

I am working of csv file with c#, I am able to return the number of rows and columns of the file, however I am still need to check if the there a new row is added to the file as well as if has empty cell or not.

any idea?

````
           {
               var contents = File.ReadAllText(item).Split('\n');
               var csv = from line in contents
                         select line.Split(';').ToArray();
               list.Add(new CSVFile
               {
                   Colums = csv.FirstOrDefault().Count(),
                   Rows = contents.Length - 1,
                   Date = DateTime.Now,
                   Report = item.Split("\\").LastOrDefault(),
                   
                   
               });
           }```
````

Comment: I think just checking for 2 consecutive delimiters should do. So in this case, if your line has `;;` then it is a blank value.

Comment: What do you consider an empty cell? Only `;;` or do `;   ;`, `;"";` and `;"  ";` also qualifies as empty cell?